# How to point a domain to my web server

Tags: node.js, domain, godaddy, nameserver

I have set up a web server using node.js on one of my computers in my house. Godaddy gives me the option to point it to an IP address. I know that all of the computers in my house have the same IP address, so how do I point it to the one with the web server running on it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a static IP address?

Comment: Static or Dynamic, it will still work. However, if it's a Dynamic IP Address, you'll need to keep updating GoDaddy so it points to the new Dynamic address. Make sure you have your firewall setup right too, and if your ISP is doing some routing, you may run into some problems, so you might need to contact your ISP in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your router to redirect requests to port 80 (or your preferred port) to a single computer in your home network. This is called [port forwarding](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router).